# Advanced comparison of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am currently making a program for a school project which is supposed to help farmers overfertilize less (this is kind of a big deal in Denmark). The way the program is supposed to work is that you enter some information about your fields(content of NPK, field size, type of dirt and other things), and then i'll be able to compare their field's content of nutrition to the recommended amount. Then I can create the theoretical ideal composition of fertilizer for this field.

This much I have been able to do, but here is the hard part.

I have a long list of fertilizers that are available in Denmark, and I want my program to compare 10 of them to my theoretical ideal composition, and then automatically pick the one that fits best.

I literally have *no* idea how to do this!

The way I format my fertilizer compositions is in lists like this

```
>>>print(idealfertilizercomp)
[43.15177154944473, 3.9661554732945534, 43.62771020624008, 4.230565838180857, 5.023796932839768]
```

Each number represent one element in percent. An example could be the first number, 43.15177154944473, which is the amount of potassium I want in my fertilizer in percent.

TL;DR:
How do I make a program or function that can compare a one list of integers to a handfull other lists of integers, and then pick the one that fits best?

Comment: What is a criteria of "fits best"?

Comment: "fits best" as in "deviates the least from the original values", so that
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] fits better with [0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99] than [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]

Comment: Doesn't sound like a coding problem to me. Can you show some code, any code, and explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

So, while i had dinner i actually came up with a way to compare multiple lists in proportion to another:

```
  def numeric(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return -x


def comparelists(x,y):
    z1 = numeric(x[0]-y[0])
    z2 = numeric(x[1]-y[1])
    z3 = numeric(x[2]-y[2])
    z4 = numeric(x[3]-y[3])
    z5 = numeric(x[4]-y[4])
    zt = z1+z2+z3+z4+z5
    return zt


def compare2inproportion(x, y, z):
    n1 = (comparelists(x, y))
    n2 = (comparelists(x, z))
    print(n1)
    print(n2)

    if n1 < n2:
        print(y, "is closer to", x, "than", z)
    elif n1 > n2:
        print(z, "is closer to", x, "than", y)
    else:
        print("Both", y, "and", z, "are equally close to", x)

idealfertilizer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fertilizer1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
fertilizer2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

compare2inproportion(idealfertilizer, fertilizer1, fertilizer2)
```

This is just a basic version that compares two lists, but its really easy to expand upon. The output looks like this:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] is closer to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] than [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Sorry for taking your time, and thanks for the help.